# Cuando alguien tenga, llegue, corra, etc... ¿que tiempo verbal es?

Tags: tiempos-verbales

Me interesa saber como se llama al tiempo verbal en las frases:

Cuando alguien **llega**.

Cuando alguien **tenga**.

Cuando alguien **corra**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En la primer frase para que sea el mismo tiempo, se diría

> Cuando alguien llegue

Se nota la diferencia en que las frases 2 y 3 dejan la posibilidad de que no ocurra la acción.

> Cuando alguien tenga paciencia, puede sentarse a escribir

En cambio la primera frase significa que se sabe que alguien alguna vez llegó.

> Cuando alguien llega, el sensor lo detecta y abre la puerta.

Entonces, si cambiamos la primera frase, nos estaríamos refiriendo al caso de tiempo verbal Presente del Modo Subjuntivo, para todas las frases.

Este es un sitio práctico para investigar los tiempos verbales:
[Referencia del lenguaje Español](http://www.esfacil.eu/es/verbos/conjugacion.html)

Answer (score 1):

El tiempo verbal de las tres frases es el **presente**, pero varía el modo de las mismas:

> Cuando alguien llega

es el presente del modo **indicativo**.  Expresa una acción indicada o concreta, en este caso algo que sucede cada vez que alguna persona llega.

> Cuando alguien tenga
>
> Cuando alguien corra

es el presente del modo **subjuntivo**.  Expresa una acción probable o hipotética.  En este caso algo que sucedería cuando se cumpla una condición.

Usando oraciones completas:

> Cuando alguien llega, saluda.

Indicación general de que cada vez que una persona llega, debe saludar (porque se ha hecho antes y se seguirá haciendo).

> Cuando alguien llegue, avise a los demás.

Hipótesis.  Nadie ha llegado o quienes han llegado no han avisado: se conmina a que la próxima persona en llegar (si la hay) avise.